# MooTools SqueezeBox unbing all events from backdrop

Tags: squeezebox

How do I unbind all events from SqueezeBox backdrop modal? I have tried

```
jQuery('#sbox-overlay').unbind('click')
```

but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

try to do this in your onload block.

```
jQuery('#sbox-overlay').off()
```

regards